# HttpServletRequest GetAttribute is null after being set inside of doAnswer

Tags: mocking, mockito

I'm currently running into an issue where I'm not able to verify the value of the Attribute that I have set inside of the doAnswer.

When I assert the value at the end of my test I am seeing that my Attribute is null, which doesn't make sense to me as I would assume that I would see the string test. Any idea on what I am doing wrong here.

Mocked Variables -

```
    @Mock
    private TwoSVRequestWrapper request;
    @Mock
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
    @InjectMocks
    private TwoStepTransactionFilter filter;
```

Test -

```
    @Test
    public void testDoFilter() throws IOException, ServletException {
        when(transactionManager.retrieveStoredTransaction("thisisarandomtransactioncode"))
                .thenReturn(transaction);
        when(factory.createMapper("Transaction")).thenReturn(mapper);

        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            TwoSVRequestWrapper requestWrapper = invocation.getArgumentAt(1,  TwoSVRequestWrapper.class);
            requestWrapper.setAttribute("Test", "test");
            return null;
        }).when(mapper).mapObject(transaction, request);


        filter.doFilter2(request,response, chain);

        verify(chain).doFilter(request,response);
        verify(transactionManager).retrieveStoredTransaction("thisisarandomtransactioncode");
        verify(factory).createMapper("Transaction");
        verify(mapper).mapObject(transaction, request);

        assertEquals( "test", request.getAttribute("Test"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm misusing my mock object in my test, to achieve the result that I wanted I instead used the verify function to verify that my request wrapper called the setAttribute method a single time with the two string values.